# SQL query column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to SQL here. I tried WITH clause today and can't figure out why I get an error from my query.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE actor
(
   actor_id
   first_name
   last_name
   last_update
)
  
CREATE TABLE film_actor
(
   actor_id
   film_id
   last_update
)

CREATE TABLE film
(
   film_id
   title
   release_year
   rating
)
```

Query that causes the error:

```
WITH tempotable(actorwithid) AS
(
    SELECT 
        actor.actor_id, first_name, last_name,film_id 
    FROM 
        actor
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
    WHERE 
        first_name = 'Nick' 
        AND last_name = 'Wahlberg'
)
SELECT 
    title, film.film_id, first_name, last_name, actor_id
FROM 
    film
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tempotable ON film.film_id = tempotable.film_id
ORDER BY 
    film_id
```

I can get desired outcome if I switch second left outer join table but I also want actor_id column in my final outcome. After add extra SELECT actor_id in second join, an error: column "actor_id" does not exist pop up. But actor_id column suppose the first column in the tempotable.

I tried tempotable.actor_id still same error.
This is a question from Udemy online sql lessons. Very appreciate for any help!

Comment: Try listing all the columns along with `(actorwithid)`. Or just use `as actorwithid` inside the query definition if you want to alias the first column.

Comment: Post the table structures, i.e. CREATE TABLE statements.  Also, when using a JOIN it's a good practice to prefix *all* columns with a table name or alias, so anyone reading the sql immediately knows which columns belong to which tables.

Comment: Looking again I'm back to removing `(actorwithid)`. The error probably says the numbers of columns doesn't match or something similar.

Comment: Thank you all for reply. I just added table structure and in that video he used multiple join for this problem. But I want try something different end up confused myself.

Comment: Remove (actorwithid) worked.  Thank you agian for your help!